# Polymorphism:Assigning child class to superclass

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, polymorphism

Are the both same?

```
ParentClass object=new ChildClass();

ParentClass object = (ParentClass) new ChildClass();
```

If I want to create a map which maps a string to Children Objects like

```
"dog"->childA;
"cat"->childB
```

How should I declare the Map?

```
Map<String,Parent>
or
Mpa<String,T extends Parent>
```

I am not sure if the second one is right or not but I read it somewhere

Answer (score 5):

> Are the both same?

Casting is unnecessary in the 2nd assignment. The first one is valid assignment. You can assign a child class object to super class reference.

> How should I declare the Map?

You should declare it the first way. A `Map<String, Parent>` will be capable of holding instances of Parent or any of it's subclasses.

As for your 2nd declaration:

```
Map<String, T extends Parent>  // This won't compile
```

this is not the correct way to specify bound in type parameter while declaring map. You can't use bounded type parameter there. You should either use a wildcard bound, or just a type parameter - `Map<String, T>`, with bounds for `T` being declared where you declare that type (perhaps in the generic class where you declare the map). So, you can use `<? extends Parent>`. The issue with declaring map this way is that, you won't be able to add anything into it, accept `null`.

**Related Post:**

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1679863)

**Reference:**

- [Angelika Langer - Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/Features.html)

  - [What is the difference between a wildcard bound and a type parameter bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20a%20wildcard%20bound%20and%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)

Answer (score 1):

The cast and non-cast are indeed the same.

For the generic, if you declare it with `<String, ? extends Parent>`, you won;t be able to add things to the list due to the fact that if it was declared `<String, Child>` parents couldn't be added. If `NewChild` was created by another dev, then we can;t know if `Parent`, `Child`, or `NewChild` is used and writes would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are identical in effect. Casting is unnecessary.

If you want the map to contain a mixture of child classes, you need to declare

```
Map<String,Parent>
```

If you declare

```
Map<String,T extends Parent>
```

it declares a map from `String` to one particular child class of type `T`. The type parameter will need to be specified elsewhere (as a type parameter to the containing class or to an enclosing method). Note that you cannot instantiate a `Map` of an unbound type. Thus, for instance:

```
Map<String,? extends Parent> = new HashMap<String, ? extends Parent>();
```

generates a compiler error. The best you could do is:

```
Map<String,? extends Parent> = new HashMap<String, Parent>();
```

in which case you might as well stick with

```
Map<String,Parent> = new HashMap<String, Parent>();
```